# NumberFormatException parsing multiple numbers in a single string

Tags: java, numberformatexception

So i was writing a code to add the no present in an array and i got a runtime as :

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input
>   string: "1000000001 1000000002 1000000003 1000000004 1000000005"  at
>   java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
>     at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:589)  at
>   java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:631)   at
>   Solution.main(Solution.java:20)

For the following code so what should i change in my code please help. Here's the code:

```
import java.io.*;
public class Solution {



public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException 
{
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)) ;
    int n= Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
    long ar[] = new long[n];
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        ar[i] = Long.parseLong(br.readLine()); 
    }
    Long sum =0L;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        sum= sum + ar[i];
    }
    System.out.println(sum);
} 
}
```

Comment: Try using `Scanner` and `nextInt()` .

Comment: You're trying to parse entire lines of input (multiple numbers) including spaces as a single number. Why are you expecting that to work?

Comment: By the way, you should be using BigInteger class rather than Long for adding those large numbers

Answer (score 1):

You are reading a complete line which is

```
"1000000001 1000000002 1000000003 1000000004 1000000005"
```

not a valid number to be parsed.

First break it with  `<space>` and convert them individually.

Comment: after i split the no, how am i supposed to put them in a string ? what's the syntax ?

Answer (score 1):

If this

```
"1000000001 1000000002 1000000003 1000000004 1000000005"
```

is your input to `Long.parseLong()`, the exception means, that this is no number.
A number does not contain spaces.
If you want to parse the numbers in that line separately, you need to split the line up before you do so. E.g.

```
String[] numberStrings = br.readLine().split(" ");
```

And then you can do `Long.parseLong()` for each element of `numberStrings`.

**EDIT what you need to change**

Instead of this:

```
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    ar[i] = Long.parseLong(br.readLine()); 
}
```

you need to do this:

```
String[] numberStrings = br.readLine().split(" ");
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    ar[i] = Long.parseLong(numberStrings[i]); 
}
```

Comment: can you please elaborate ? i'm just a noob and this is beyond me.

Answer (score 0):

you are giving all the inputs in a single line you should give the inputs in different lines